# How to easily order an array from largest to smallest in Visual C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a small array of ints.  I want to reorder the array from largest to smallest.  Is there a method to do this?

Answer (score 12):

You could use [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf.aspx):

```
int[] array = new[] { 1, 3, 2 };
Array.Sort(array, (x, y) => y.CompareTo(x));
```

As far as complexity is concerned:

> On average, this method is an O(n log
>   n) operation, where n is the Length of
>   array; in the worst case it is an O(n
>   ^ 2) operation

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using `Array` `Sort` & `Reverse`:

```
Array.Sort(array);
Array.Reverse(array);
```

Example:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var array = new[] { 1, 3, 2 };
    Array.Sort(array);
    Array.Reverse(array);

    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new[] { 3, 2, 1 }, array);
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort%28VS.71%29.aspx
and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.reverse%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this

```
int[] ints = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3};
var sorted = ints.OrderBy(i => i);
```

Found at [Sort array of items using OrderBy<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620534/sort-array-of-items-using-orderby)

Comment: For largest to smallest:
ints.OrderByDescending(i => i);