# sorting on generic list after using .Toarray method

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, sorting

I am using following code to bind a paged datasource to repeater control

```
  protected void Paging()
    {
        Array q = (Array)Session["q"];
        PagedDataSource objPds = new PagedDataSource();
        objPds.DataSource = q;
        objPds.AllowPaging = true;
        objPds.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(ddlPageNo.SelectedValue);

        objPds.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;

        lblCurrentPage.Text = "Page: " + (CurrentPage + 1).ToString() + " of "
           + objPds.PageCount.ToString();

        // Disable Prev or Next buttons if necessary
        cmdPrev.Enabled = !objPds.IsFirstPage;
        cmdNext.Enabled = !objPds.IsLastPage;

        rptHotels.DataSource = objPds;
        rptHotels.DataBind();

    }
```

where `q` is

```
 getAvailableHotelResponse getres = new getAvailableHotelResponse();    
  getres = objsoap.getAvailableHotel(apiKey, destinationId, checkIn, checkOut, strCurrencyCode, "UK", false, rooms, f);   
            List<hotel> hr = new List<hotel>();
            hr = getres.availableHotels.ToList();

            List<BALHotelList> bh = new List<BALHotelList>();
            bh = h.GetHotelListByDestinationId(destinationId);
     var q = from a in bh
                    join b in hr on a.HotelCode equals b.hotelCode
                    orderby a.HotelName
                    select new
            {
                a.HotelCode,
                a.ImageURL_Text,
                a.HotelName,
                a.StarRating,
                a.HotelAddress,
                a.Destination,
                a.Country,
                a.HotelInfo,
                a.Latitude,
                a.Longitude,
                b.totalPrice,
                b.totalPriceSpecified,
                b.totalSalePrice,
                b.totalSalePriceSpecified,
                b.rooms

            };


            //rptHotels.DataSource = getres.availableHotels;

            Session["q"] = q.ToArray();
```

now i want to use

want to sort the array q by `hotelname` or `starRating` .

I am not finding any method like

```
q.sort();
```

or

```
q.orderBy(q->hotelName)
```

Comment: add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @TimSchmelter i already have this namespace included .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`q` for you is an instance of the `Array` class, rather than an array of some type (i.e. `int[]`, `string[]`, `object[]`).  `Array` only implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>` so the Linq methods aren't there.  The underlying problem here is that it is an array of an anonymous type, so other than through using really messy workarounds you can't effectively get a strongly typed array back.

The best solution at this point is to create a new class to hold your data (i.e. `Hotel`) rather than putting it into an anonymous type.  When you populate the session create new instances of that type (`Hotel`) , and then when you pull it out of the session cast it to an array of that type (`Hotel[]`), rather then the generic `Array`.  At that point you will be able to use the Linq methods on the object.

Comment: i already using two classes one is BALHotel and Hotel and q is inner join result of two classes object. and i dont think it will be a good approach to create a new class which just hold result of two classes object inner join . Is it right approach ?

Comment: If you already have a `Hotel` class then you'll need to use a different name, but you almost certainly want to create a new concrete class for this.  Anonymous types are designed to be used within the scope of a single method body, and not persisted between methods.  Creating a new concrete class is going to be the path of least resistance here.

Comment: yes,thats the actual problem is that var is only used with in method , we can not declare var as global .

Comment: should i create separate class for each result when i apply this type of join ?

Comment: @rahularyansharma If you are only going to use the result within the scope of a single method, no, there is no need.  When you want to either return the results, or store it in a field so that it can be accessed elsewhere, then yes, you'll want to make a concrete class.

Answer (score 2):

For an in-place sort of an existing array by a member:

```
Array.Sort(theArray, (x,y) => string.Compare(x.HotelName, y.HotelName));
```

Answer (score 2):

use following..

```
q.OrderBy(x => x.HotelName);
```

**UPDATE**

casting back from session, do it like this

```
//if you have concrete type instead of object, use that type

var t = (IEnumerable<object>)Session["q"];
```

**UPDATE 2**

your projection should be a concrete type (i.e make a new Hotel class to represent your projection) , otherwise you would not be able to do OrderBy on some property of your projection

Comment: I believe it should be: `q.OrderBy(result -> result.HotelName);` ...you don't need `ToList()`

Comment: @Anand there is not appearing  method OrderBy on q

Comment: @Anand sysem.array does not contain a definition  for OrderBy

Comment: see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx.
Its an extension method on Enumerable class. It should be there. Array is also Enumerable

Comment: You need System.Core assembly and System.Linq namespace

Comment: you still won't be able to sot on a parameter at that point, it's now just an enumerable of objects.