# Sorting on C# arrays using OrderBy

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I am using the OrderBy to create a new sorted array as suggested in the post *[Sort array of items using OrderBy<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620534/sort-array-of-items-using-orderby/18493235#18493235)* .

```
var sorted = sharepointList.OrderBy(item => item.GetTabOrder()).ToArray();
```

where, sharepointList is the array of objects that contains attributes including int tabOrder
 and GetTabOrder is the getter for the 'tabOrder' attribute

But this throws the below Exception. Please help

NullReferenceException

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Thanks in advance,
 Sagarika

Comment: Either your collection is null, or an item in the collection is null.  If neither should be the case, you have a bug somewhere.  If null values are "allowed" then you need to check for null first.

Comment: How do you want to order if the `item is null`? first or last?

Comment: @mservidio `GetTabOrder` returning null wouldn't cause a null reference exception. The exception is caused by him calling `GetTabOrder()` on a null reference. Or if sharepointList is null, calling OrderBy on a null reference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a null value in your `sharepointList`. If you do;

```
  var sorted = sharepointList.Where(x => x != null).OrderBy(item => item.GetTabOrder()).ToArray();
```

It will prevent the exception, but null values will be excluded from your result.

Your entire list could be null in which case you need;

```
     if (sharepointList != null) 
         //order by in here
     else
         //handle error
```

Answer (score -1):

Either sharepointList is null

or item is null

or something in GetTabOrder() is null

Answer (score -1):

With visual studio you can pass the mouse above one variable and VS will popup the value of the variabile (Can help you to know what is the variabile with null)

Comment: Thanks.The problem was with the default null values when the array was initialized. I had fewer data than the array length and was not aware that they would be initialized to null. I am a newbie to C# and was under the impression that there would be junk values if the array is not initialized. Just learnt that it would be nulls. Thanks for the quick replies.